# VB6: make default response in InputBox not highlighted?

Tags: vb6, highlight, inputbox

In VB6 (and earlier), is there a way to have the default response in an InputBox to be non-highlighted?

Comment: Writing your own version of the InputBox will be a lot less painful

Comment: As CodeByMoonlight says, the InputBox is such a basic dialog so it's easier to create your own version than to try to customize it in any way.

Comment: I would prefer to utilise a pre-made dialog. It would take far less time if it could be configured to do what I want.

Comment: Yes, it *would*. But since configuring it will probably involve a lot of API hacking, it will take *more* time in the end than just writing a custom InputBox.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial for a custom InputBox in VB.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103846-custom-inputbox/). Hope it gives you a lead as to how to implement such functionality in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run on Vista or later, you could try this kludge:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Timer1.Interval = 250
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    InputBox "no selection", "no sel", "default value"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    SendKeys "{RIGHT}", False
End Sub
```

To test, create a form with:
    • Command button
• Timer control, and use default names.